# Возможно ли сделать SQL инъекцию

Tags: python, sql, telegram-bot, sql-injection

Возможно ли в данной части кода провести SQL инъекцию. Если да, то как решить эту проблему?

```
def currency_quotes_input(message, base_message):
    History().base_current_input(message)


def base_current_input(self, data):
    self.cursor.execute(f"SELECT code_currency FROM iso_code_keys WHERE currency_key = '{data.text.lower()}'")
    self.currency = self.cursor.fetchone()[0]
    self.cursor.execute(
        f"INSERT INTO history(user_id, base_currency) VALUES({data.from_user.id}, '{self.currency}')")
    self.commit()
```

Comment: Да, возможно. Почему бы вам не использовать второй аргумент метода execute, чтобы полностью исключить даже теоретическую возможность sql-инъекций?

Comment: Можете подсказать какой мне аргумент использовать?

Comment: А какую базу вы используете и откуда вы берёте self.cursor?

Comment: PostgreSQL через psycopg2  self.conn = psycopg2.connect() self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

Comment: self.cursor.execute(f"SELECT code_currency FROM iso_code_keys WHERE currency_key = ''%s''",  data.text.lower()). Я походу нашел, вы это имели ввиду?

Comment: Да, только второй аргумент должен быть не строка, а кортеж `(data.text.lower(),)`

Comment: И вместо `WHERE currency_key = ''%s''` должно быть просто `WHERE currency_key = %s` потому что psycopg2 сам подставит все нужные кавычки

Comment: Спасибо, а можете объяснить почему это исключает SQL инъекцию?

Comment: Потому что psycopg2 автоматически экранирует все перечисленные элементы в этом кортеже